# How to force evaluation on the right of an @ operator?

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, functional-style

Is there a way to force evaluation on the right before the Prefix operator (`@`) without using parentheses? I came across this question when I was working with the following example:

I have a list of substitutions like this:

```
lst1 = {{a -> 1 , b -> 2}, {a -> 3, b -> 4}, {a -> 5, b -> 6}}
```

I am trying to put it in a grid form, to look like this:

```
a  b
1  2
3  4
5  6
```

I get this code working:

```
Grid @ (Join @@ { Keys @ Take[#, 1], Values @ # } & @ lst1 )
```

However, it only works with the parenthese `(   )` around the `Join` expression.
Is there a way in Mathematica to force everything on the right of an `@` to get evaluated first?

I wish I can right something like:

```
Grid @ Join @@ { Keys @ Take[#, 1], Values @ # } & @ lst1
```

Which instead yields:

```
Grid[Join][{{a, b}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}]
```

The reason I am trying to do that, is basically, when I get to apply many functions in this way, it becomes cumbersome to always have to close the parentheses at the end (which defeats my purpose of using the `@` operator in the first place). 
I am mostly looking for an equivalent to the `$` operator in Haskell, if such thing exists.

Comment: Thanks @Szabolcs for your comment, I fixed my question to refer to @ as Prefix operator (my mistake). ... Thanks for your answer, it is sad to hear there isn't such a thing.

Comment: No, there isn't, because `@` has a very high precedence.  The issue is with precedences.  Should `x OP1 y OP2 z` be interpreted as `(x OP1 y) OP2 z` or `x OP1 (y OP2 z)`?  In Mathematica it's the latter only if `OP2` has a higher precedence than `OP1`.

Comment: Instead of `f @ (g @@ x)` you might want to use `f @ Apply[g] @ x`, which is more verbose, but does save parentheses.  Unfortunately when you use pure functions (`...&` notation), very often it's still necessary to use parens because `&` has a low precedence and tends to "eat" everything preceding it.

Comment: Thanks @Szabolcs for the explanation, indeed `f @ Apply[g] @ x` does the trick. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Using only prefix operators: `Grid@Flatten[#, 1] &@{{#}, # /. lst1} &@{a, b}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @MichaelE2 in the comments, I ended up using the [composition operator](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) `@*`. My final code looks like:

```
Grid @* Join @@ {Keys@Take[#, 1], Values@#}& @ lst1
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `f @ (g @@ x)` you can use `f @ Apply[g] @ x` (since Mathematica 10).  This is more verbose, but it saves parentheses.  Since visually matching parentheses is hard, I think that the latter variant is more readable, especially when there's a long chain of functions.

This style can be used with postfix too (`x // Apply[g] // f`) and it makes it easy to add or remove functions at any position in the chain without having to worry about precedences.

Most important operators, such as `Map`, `Apply`, `Replace`, etc. support this style.

Comment: Similarly `f @* g @@ x` works, too.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Can you elaborate more on that? What does `@*` mean in this case? (I like this more ... )

Comment: @Bichoy It is short for `Composition`.  You can search [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616) for `@*` and other such forms.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2, this is indeed a marvelous answer :) Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Grid[Join[
  Transpose[Union /@ GatherBy[Flatten[lst1], First][[All, All, 1]]],
  Transpose[Union /@ GatherBy[Flatten[lst1], First][[All, All, 2]]]]]
```

which of course can be streamlined...

Comment: Sorry David, I am mostly asking about the Prefix operator `@` and evaluation precedence. I am sorry if my question in its current form isn't clear enough.